# Java beans binding property to polar coordinate equation

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, binding

I'm trying to bind the startXProperty of a JavaFX QuadCurve to the rotation of a node by using the radius r of the node and its rotation θ. The idea being if I do this with the Y property as well I can have the curve 'attach' its self to the end of a rotating object.

Now I know the x value can be found using `x = r × cos( θ )`.

But I'm struggling to represent this in the Bindings math:

```
curve.startXProperty().bind(getRod().rotateProperty().//Something);
```

I'm trying to think of a combination of the `.multiply()`, `.divide()`, `.add()` and `.subtract()` I have avaliable. It's not like the bindings have a .cos() method I can easily use.

Would love it if someone could help me solve this headscratcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `add`, `multiply`, ect. methods are just for convenience.

Luckily the `Bindings` class allows you tp specify arbitrary bindings that can be used as parameter for the binding:

```
DoubleBinding binding = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                                    () -> Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getRod().getRotate())) * radiusProperty.get(),
                                    getRod().rotateProperty(),
                                    radiusProperty);

curve.startXProperty().bind(binding);
```

You may however be better of using a listener to the `rotate` property, applying [`localToParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToParent-double-double-) as transformation and setting the properties of `curve` to the results provided.

Comment: Thanks fabian for the answer just what I needed, I've never used localToParent but I'll give it a try :)